# Java EE container - self managed threads?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, jboss, glassfish

Is it possible to start for example a OrientDB Server Instance inside a Java EE server?

Is this possible or do i need to use only Servlets or EJB inside the containers?

Can you give me a quick example on how to do start an application that manages it's own threads please.

Comment: Quartz does it, so yes it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to start an app in JavaEE. JavaEE server does not force you to not use your own threads.

Here's an exmaple of how to start a embedded (in process) HSQLDB:

```
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:testdb", "sa", "");
```

Of course you need to run the code the starts in process OrientDB, I don't think that OrientDB can be started this way (in process). It has to have it's own process.

Comment: I suspected this, as you said it seems like i have to start the server outside the application server in it's own process

Answer (score 2):

You can start OrientDB in the same JVM, even a Java EE container. Look at this guide: http://code.google.com/p/orient/wiki/EmbeddedServer.

You could create a Servlet that simply follow the instructions to start the server.